# how do i fix this simple windows forms application

Tags: c#, string, io, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I'm pretty new in C# and I'm trying to do a windows forms application and i have come to a problem. So basically what my program does, it reads a number from a .txt file and multiplies it with a number that the user gives in a textBox. Then it tells the answer in another textBox when the user presses a button. So my problem is that when it tries to read the .txt file and transfer it to a double and multiply it something goes wrong and the program crashes. I have included my button's code below'

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double answer;
    double num;
    double Filename = double.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:/temp/hinnat.txt"));
    num = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    answer = Filename * num;
    textBox2.Text = answer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is the exception you get? Post the exception name, message, stacktrace.

Comment: what are the contents of a text file?

Comment: This could be a number of things.  The file does not exist.  The file or textbox1 contain values that cannot be parsed into a double.  You need to provide the error you receive to you can be helped further.

Comment: irrelevant, but `Filename` is a **terrible** name for a `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TryParse instead in case the text is not valid

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double answer;
    double num;
    double Filename 
    if (double.TryParse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:/temp/hinnat.txt"), out Filename)
       && double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out num))
    {
        answer = Filename * num;
        textBox2.Text = answer.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution got rid of the error, but the program refuses to print the answer on the textBox, basically the button does nothing when i have written the numbers on the textBox1. Also the error message in my code was "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Oh, never mind this solution worked. I had accidentally put a dot  in the decimal number in the .txt file (dumb me). Anyway thank you David for helping me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Double.Parse** and **Double.TryParse** methods depend on the culture, i.e. in some cultures the decimal separator is dot ('.') like in **10.5**, while in other cultures the decimal separator is comma (',') like in **10,5**. That is why if you are not sure what input you might have in the text file or what's the current culture of your application it's best to have a custom **TryParse** method that replaces any comma with dot and parses the string to double using the Invariant culture:

```
private static bool TryParse(string str, out double result)
{
    // Invariant culture uses dot ('.') as decimal separator, so replace any comma with dot
    if (str.IndexOf(',') != -1)
    {
        str = str.Replace(',', '.');
    }

    // Try parsing with the Invariant culture
    return Double.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result);
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/temp/hinnat.txt");
double fileDouble;
if (TryParse(fileContent, out fileDouble))
{
    // Parsing was successfull
    // Your code here
}
```